# Array with random Integer

Tags: vb.net

I want to write a programm, that first generates three random integers and then prints out the square and cube of them.

[image]

I already have the calculation and the output, but I don´t know how to generate the random numbers.

```
Dim NumOfIntegers() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 8}
Dim x, y As Integer
For Each num As Integer In NumOfIntegers
    x = num ^ 2
    y = num ^ 3
    MessageBox.Show("Square Of " & num & " = " & x & vbCrLf & "Cube Of " & num & " = " & y)
Next
```

Comment: "This answer in array I want to answer in random please." Do you mean your input numbers?

Comment: Please include your screenshot as an image, not as a link. You seem to have exactly what you want (according to the screenshot). Please explain clearer what you are trying to do

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE : If I'm not mistaken new accounts aren't able to post images in their question. They need something like 10 rep. or so to do that.

Comment: @VisualVincent. Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I can't find it in the privileges list though, but you're probably right

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE : Apparently it's part of the [Remove new user restrictions privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user), although it's not stated in the description. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183926/reputation-10-to-post-images).

Comment: @VisualVincent: A saw that privilege and assumed it had something to do with it indeed, even tough it is not explicitly mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @Vicky_ThinkingI yes I want to be random numbers in loop

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE I do not know how to included them as a picture

Comment: As we've discussed you cannot include images in your post if you have less than 10 reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code fills a Integer List with 3 different random numbers between 1 and 100

```
Dim NumOfIntegers As New List(Of Integer)

While NumOfIntegers.Count < 3
    Dim i As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 100)) + 1
    If Not NumOfIntegers.Contains(i) Then NumOfIntegers.Add(i)
End While

NumOfIntegers.Sort()

Dim x, y As Integer    
For Each num As Integer In NumOfIntegers
    x = num ^ 2
    y = num ^ 3
    MessageBox.Show("Square Of " & num & " = " & x & vbCrLf & "Cube Of " & num & " = " & y)
Next
```

Code if you only want to use a for loop:

(It´s untested code and within the 3 Integers might be duplicates)

```
Dim NumOfIntegers() As New Integer = {(CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 100)) + 1), (CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 100)) + 1), (CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 100)) + 1)}

Dim x, y As Integer    
For Each num As Integer In NumOfIntegers
    x = num ^ 2
    y = num ^ 3
    MessageBox.Show("Square Of " & num & " = " & x & vbCrLf & "Cube Of " & num & " = " & y)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but I want another way and probably the easiest.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "another way"?

Comment: I mean, for example, using for instead of while

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe this solution fits better for you

Comment: Thank you, I wish you a special day.